# Approach to making a 2D graphic 3D?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I've been given a logo graphic that is solid black, in 2D.  The best way to describe is to visualize a musical treble clef drawn with a wide-tip pen slanted. There are two important characteristics that I'm trying to figure out how to model using Blender (2.69): 1) The wide-tip pen (calligraphy style) causes the width of the stroke to change continuously, and 2) the stroke crosses over itself twice.  The 3D request is to have the stroke be "raised" in the middle.

I have the outline of the logo traced perfectly with a bezier curve, but I can't figure out how to give it a smooth contour that changes height to match the width of the stroke.

Conceptually I'd like to extrude a bezier circle along the outline, scaling each extrusion to match the width of the stroke.  When done I'd bring a plane in and have it bisect the model between a lower or back half and the upper or front half.

But every way I've tried to extrude a bezier curve results in the curve just moving along with my cursor.  I was hoping to use bezier curves to keep the quality of the curve high until I was done shaping the entire model, then convert the curve to mesh and clean up where the stroke overlaps.

Perhaps a workable approach is to create a circle mesh, extrude it, rotate as needed, and scale it, then repeat all along the outline. However, I absolutely have to avoid faceted curves as the "skin" flows around the stroke.

I am hoping someone more experienced with Blender would have a helpful suggestion or two.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but you might want to look at using [*Bevel and taper objects*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Geometry). If that doesn't help, you could use a mesh and use [smooth shading](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Smoothing#Smooth_shading) and [subsurf](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf) to make things smoother. Could you upload some screenshots to further explain your problem and the desired result?

Comment: you can just extrude the overlapping part and few adjoining faces to give it a raised look. Use Proportional editing tool to move the selected faces, as it gives smooth taper to new extruded faces.

Comment: Thank you, both, for your suggestions.  The proportional editing one gave me absolute fits until I found out how to decrease the size of the influence.  But ultimately I just increased the geometry and tweaked individual vertices until I was happy enough to move on.

Comment: A picture paints a thounsand words. It would be really nice that you can upload a sample image to show what exactly you want to make.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Extrude your outline to create a "flat topped" shape.

Switch to a side view and create a curve that describes the peak at the "stroke cross" the way you're visualizing.

Extrude your profile view curve along the horizontal axis to create a shape that intersects and contains your logo.

Boolean intersect.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion.  I think it would work for most normal work, but because mine has the shape wrapping around and through itself at constantly changing width and height, I couldn't figure out a profile that would work.  I ended up increasing mesh geometry and pulling vertices to sort of smooth things out (looks like a jagged jigsaw puzzle now!) and worked on lighting and material to hide it mostly.